# is it possible to load an external application inside a JSF 2 application?

Tags: jsf-2, oracle-adf

i need to have a button in my JSF application (im using the Intellij IDE), and when i press that button i load another application that was made in Jdeveloper using ADF. that app scan a website and extract data from there to add it into a database.

i see a little hard to move the complete application to my JSF project, i dont think it is even possible.

what i would like to have is something like this:

```
<p:commandButton  actionListener="#{loadotherAPP}" value="Cargar" ajax="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the application in a new browser window or you can open it in **iframe**!

Comment: i dont need it that way.. i need to click a button on my jsf view and somehow execute the other app.

Comment: Did you think about application communication, using web services for example? I don't think that's possible in other way.